# In Scala how can I reflect on a typedef (eg. type Data = Map[String,Any])?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm writing some reflection code.  I have a class like this:

```
case class Foo(
   info : Map[String,Any]
)
```

I reflect on this class like this:

```
ctor.typeSignature.paramLists.head.map( f => {
   println("F: "+f.typeSignature)
})
```

When defined as above I see what I expect for the type of member info: Map[String,scala.Any]

But... if I do this:

```
type Data = Map[String,Any]
case class Foo(
   info : Data
)
```

Now I see the type of info as: co.blocke.scalajack.test.v4.Data

**How can I tell if a type like Data above is actually a typedef any how can I see what it resolves to?** (the type of 'f' in the clip above is universe.Symbol)

I mistakenly thought it was compiler-candy and after compilation it would have resolved to its defined type, but apparently not!

Comment: How are you getting `ctor`?

Comment: ```case sym if(sym.asClass.isCaseClass) =>
  val ctor         = sym.asClass.primaryConstructor
``` whre sym is a Type.typeSymbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dealias`:

```
type Data = Map[String,Any]
case class Foo(info: Data)
```

Excuse the lack of safety measures, but to cut to the chase:

```
typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol
    .asClass
    .primaryConstructor
    .typeSignature
    .paramLists
    .head
    .head
    .typeSignature
    .dealias

res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.Any]
```

Comment: Actually I didn't do all that...  but dealias was absolutely the help I needed!  From my original example, this worked: ```f.typeSignature.dealias```.  If the type is a typedef then this unscrambles it to the actual type.  Otherwise it seems to be a harmless no-op (returns same type) for any other type.

Comment: @Greg Well yeah, all of that isn't necessary for your purpose, but I didn't have all of your code. So I just included a way to get from one end to the other to illustrate `dealias`.

Comment: Still grateful for the tip!  Scala internals are a jungle indeed.